# High perf content server in java

Tags: java, performance, zero-copy

Consider a very thin rest layer over S3 , the upload api has a file attachment ( multipart* MIME type ) . The service receives the call and forwards the bytes to S3 . 
what are  my options to optimize performance here ?? 
I  am thinking zero-copy transfer but in java that seems to be possible only between file <--> socket . What bothers me the is the overhead of the bytes flowing through my jvm where there is no tranformation or value add

EDIT 1:
By Performance I primarily mean "fastest way to serve an individual request" , consistent latency ( avoid outliers) will be second in the priority list .

Comment: When you say "performance", do you mean "fastest possible way to serve an individual request", or "graceful and predictable response when seeing growing numbers of requests"?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt updated the question to address this aspect